# check duplicate value before insert in oracle query without using trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

i need in insert query check duplicates any fields like first name if not exist in this table make insert new row and return current inserted id
and else 
if first name exist in table return zero as duplicated

not using trigger,function and proced

Comment: You say "return" but then you rule out any programmatic solution.  So what exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as an "insert query".

The normal way to implement such a requirement would be with a data integrity constraint:

```
alter table your_table 
    add constraint your_table_uk unique (first_name)
/
```

This would raise any exception if you attempt to insert a duplicate record.

To get the currently inserted ID:

```
insert into your_table (id, first_name)
    values (your_seq.nextval, 'SAM-I-AM')
    returning id
/
```

You say you don't want to use a function or a procedure but the only way to return 0 if the submitted `first_name` is a duplicate would be programmatic:

```
create or replace function new_record (p_name your_table.first_name%type)
    return your_table.id%type
is
    return_value your_table.id%type;
begin
    begin
        insert into your_table (id, first_name)
            values (your_seq.nextval, p_first_name)
        returning id into return_value;
    exception
        when dup_val_on_index then
             return_value := 0;
    end;
    return return_value;
end;
```

Comment: what can i do if i want to pass insert statement to this function as a parameter and executed it in function and return value